# Material-Design-Lite, Override styleguide property without !important

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I'm playing with Material-Design-Lite and I want to override a style but it won't work. Let say that I woudl like to change the padding on `mdl-navigation__link` which is actually `16px 40px` to `0px`.

I have overrided the property on my custom style sheet but without success. However some other styles are applied :

```
.my-navigation .mdl-navigation__link {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The border is applied but not the padding. And into teh web develope tools I see that my padding property is ignored (strikethrough) du to a `styleguide.css` that I never include !

I suppose that `styleguide.css` is included by the javascript file. So the only trick to apply my custom padding is to mark it as `!important`.

Is it a cleaner way to override `styleguide.css` properties ?

**Edit :**
Here is the codepen :
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGjYqo

Comment: `styleguide.css` is not provided via JS or via the builds. It is only for the microsite. Can you please show us some reproduction code via a codepen or similar?

Comment: Of course, the codepen is at the end of the original post

Comment: I'm not seeing any styleguide.css requests. However, the JS also is non-functioning so if it is the cause of the problem, who knows why. Make sure the codepen is fully functional, not just a copy & paste of your local source.

Comment: Sorry, he is now fully functional. Details of my problem in the "content' of the codepen result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to increase the specificity of your selectors. Check the specificity of what MDL provides. `.mdl-layout__drawer .mdl-navigation .mdl-navigation__link`. This is a 3-class specificity, so about 30. You are doing a two class selector, so roughly 20 specificity. Whether yours comes after or not, the high specificity wins.

Some good resources on specificity:

- [Smashing
  Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Instead of doubling it. I have specified it much more `.pgrn-navigation.mdl-navigation .mdl-navigation__link`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling up the classes. Even if they are the same class the specificity will be greater than it was when selecting only one.

Perfect for allowing overrides without resorting to `!important`

for example:

```
.mdl-navigation__link.mdl-navigation__link {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

More tricks like this for lower specificity at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/)

And my favorite guide on [CSS Specificity](http://cssspecificity.com/)