# Add padding to min-height instead of including it?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

Is there a way to have the padding on an element be added to the `min-height` value instead of being included in it? For example you have `10px` of padding on the  top and bottom a element and a min-height of `150px` the height should be `170px` instead of the element's height being `130px` + `20px` of padding.

I'm currently building a site using Material Design Lite and it adds padding to almost everything so it's a bit of a pain to have to always find the padding on something when you want to set a min-height value.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `box-sizing:content-box;`, since height shouldn't include padding in the default `content-box` model. That might break some things though, so be sure to test!

Comment: unfortunately MDL also uses `box-sizing:border-box` for pretty much everything as well so that method won't work :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding instead of trying to find it every time? [This answer goes over how specificity can help you set padding to 0 for Material Design Lite.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31457156/5914723)

Comment: Well.... if you don't mind having a [very narrow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) browser support you could mod it to set the top/bottom padding via variables, and then ref the vars in `calc()` calls. Not sure if there's any other good ways without touching the DOM.

Comment: @DanAfterFiveCoffees I don't want to remove the padding since it's used to properly space material design elements and removing it would just create a different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be a little late, but setting `box-sizing: content-box;` on the element would solve the issue.